# Problema com condição

Tags: php, condição

Estou tentando criar um script que apure se a multa por atraso no pagamento da rescisão é devida.

As condições são as seguintes:

1 - Se o aviso prévio for indenizado ou dispensado (select), e o pagamento foi feito em até 10 dias (date), a multa não é devida.

2 - Se o aviso prévio foi trabalhado ou descontado, e o pagamento foi foi feito após 1 dia do desligamento, a multa é devida.

3 - Nos demais casos não é devida.

Este é o código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/form2.css"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="Tform" action="multaqss.php">
    <label for="Cavis"><b>Aviso prévio</b><br>Como deve ser considerado o aviso prévio?</label><br>
    <select name="Tavis" id="Cavis">
        <option></option>
        <option value="indenizado">indenizado</option>
        <option value="dispensado">dispensado</option>
        <option value="trabalhado">trabalhado</option>
        <option value="descontado">descontado</option>
    </select>
<br>
    <label id="pagtss"><b>Desligamento</b></label><br>
    <label for="Cdesl22">Qual a data do desligamento?</label><br>
    <input type="date" name="Tdesl" id="Cdesl22" size="6"><br>
    <label id="datapagto"><b>Data do pagamento</b></label><br>
    <label for="Cdatapgtos">Qual a data em que foi realizado o pagamento?</label><br>
    <input type="date" id="Cdatapgtos" name="Tdatapagtos"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php

$tavis = $_POST ["Tavis"];
$fimcon = $_POST ["Tdesl"];
$pagtos = $_POST ["Tdatapagtos"];
$multaqss = false;
$prazo = date_diff(date_create($pagtos), date_create($fimcon))->format('%d');

    if ($tavis == "indenizado" || "dispensado" && $prazo > 10){
        $multaqss = true;
    }
    elseif ($tavis == "trabalhado" || "descontado" && $prazo > 1) {
        $multaqss = true;
    }

print "A data de desligamento foi $fimcon" . "<br>";
print "A data de pagamento foi $pagtos" . "<br>";
print "A diferença entre o desligamento e o pagamento é de $prazo dia(s)" . "<br>";
print "O aviso prévio foi $tavis" . "<br>";

    if ($multaqss == false) {
        echo "A multa não é devida" . "<br>";
    }
    else {
        echo "A multa é devida." . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

O problema é que não importa o que eu faça, ele sempre considera que é devido, mesmo que a data não corresponda.

Um exemplo de saída (errada):

> A data de desligamento foi 2015-04-01
>
> A data de pagamento foi 2015-04-05
>
> A diferença entre o desligamento e o pagamento é de 4 dia(s)
>
> O aviso prévio foi indenizado
>
> **A multa é devida.**

Comment: Eu não entendo muito de php, mas você não deveria separar os operadores usando parênteses, por exemplo, nessa expressão ? `($tavis == "indenizado" || "dispensado" && $prazo > 10)`

Comment: Fora ter algum problema menos visível de formato da data, parece ser isto mesmo.

Comment: Seria legal o @Carlos responder.

Comment: Em um `if` você colocou `"true"` (*string*) e no outro `true` (*boolean*). Não é este o problema mas é bom tomar cuidado com estes detalhes

Comment: Valeu Lucas, isso foi um erro mesmo, estava tentando trocar para string pra ver se dava certo, e tinha mudado todas, depois quando voltei para true/false esqueci destas aspas. Já consertei aqui, e fiz as alterações que indicaram abaixo (dos parenteses) mas ainda não resolveu.

Comment: @bigown O que pode ter de errado com o formato da data?

Comment: Não sei, é sempre uma possibilidade para quem está vendo o código mas não tem como testar. Poderia ser outra coisa, este foi apenas um exemplo, nem tudo dá p/ identificar só olhando o código. O código tem uma série de pequenos problemas mas aqui no comentário fica complicado citar todos. Mesmo que eles não estejam causando erros reais, mostra que pode ter outras coisas erradas sem estarem visíveis.

Comment: Coloquei o script no codepad (http://codepad.org/Lz3IWpUm) e deu esse erro: Fatal error: Call to undefined function date_diff() on line 7. Como isso foi a única coisa do código que peguei pronta (aqui mesmo no SOpt), acredito que o erro esteja aí (não que o código esteja errado, talvez a utilização que dei a ele...). Ele dá a saída certinho dos dias de diferença, mas de alguma forma não considera isso na condição...

Comment: Amigo só uma dica, use `isset(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente, há um erro na condição. Deve resolver alterando para:

```
if (($tavis == "indenizado" || $tavis == "dispensado") && $prazo > 10){
    $multaqss = true;
}
elseif (($tavis == "trabalhado" || $tavis == "descontado") && $prazo > 1) {
    $multaqss = true;
}
```

Comment: O if está com dois parenteses depois de dispensado", e o elseif está com apenas um. Se coloco apenas um ele funciona, mas ainda dá o mesmo erro. Se coloco dois, a outra condição fica marcada como unused pelo phpstorm. Tentei assim também:  if (($tavis == "indenizado" || "dispensado") && ($prazo > 10)) mas não resolveu.

Comment: Realmente, havia um parêntese a mais, corrigi. O  problema ao qual me referi é que a comparação não estava sendo feita com o "dispensado" nem com o "descontado".

Por isso fiz as modificações:

de '|| "dispensado"' para '|| $tavis == "dispensado"' 

e de '"|| "descontado"' para '|| $tavis == "descontado"'

Os parênteses "a mais" são para organizar o cógigo e garantir que primeiro serão checados os "ou" e só depois será verificado se o $prazo é maior que 1 ou 10, dependendo do caso.

Comment: Valeu, entendi o ponto, e deixei assim no código, mas continua não funcionando.

Comment: Nossa! Eu não tinha visto que você mudou a condição, colocando a variável novamente após o ||... eu não sabia que precisava repetir.Valeu mesmo, agora deu certo!